# PHP show a range of dates, excluding a given set of holidays and days off

Tags: php, arrays

I want to set my store pre-order date which would be based on a range of days. So let's say if I set 5 days as pre-order then it would add 5 days to the current date and show in the dropdown. But the main thing is there would be holidays and some weekdays closed

So let's say today is 14th and I make 5 days it should come days like

```
2020-09-14 ( Todays Date ) + 5 days
2020-09-15
2020-09-16
2020-09-17
2020-09-18
2020-09-19
```

But there would be chances of holidays like  15, 18 would be holidays and the store closes on each Thursday and Saturday

So in that case store would be close on

```
2020-09-15, 2020-09-18 (because of holidays)

2020-09-17, 2020-09-19 (each Thursday and Saturday off)
```

But as the store is pre-order for 5 days then it would show final dates like

```
2020-09-14
2020-09-16
2020-09-20
2020-09-21
2020-09-22
2020-09-23
```

So, for now, my code is like this

```
$data = [];
function get_store_open_days( $order_range, $initial_date ) {
  $day = 0;
  $days = [];
  $test = [];
  
  $disable_weekdays = array( '4', '6' ); //thursday and saturdays off
  $holidays = array( '2020-09-18', '2020-09-15' );

  for ( $i=0; $i <= $order_range ; $i++ ) { 
    $days[] = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $initial_date . ' + '.$i.' days' ) );
  }

  $weekdays_count = 0;
  $holiday_count = 0;
  $holiday_dates = [];
  $disabled_weekdays = [];


  if ( is_array( $days ) && !empty( $days ) ){
  
    foreach( $days as $day ) {
    
      if ( in_array( $day, $holidays ) ) {
        $holiday_dates[] = $day;
      }

      //weekdays count
      $day_number = date( 'N', strtotime( $day ) );

      if ( in_array( $day_number, $disable_weekdays ) ) {
        $disabled_weekdays[] = $day; 
      }
    }
  }

  $disabled_weekdays = array_merge( $holiday_dates, $disabled_weekdays );

  $open_days = array_diff( $days, $disabled_weekdays );


  $open_buisness_days[] = $open_days;

  $open_days_count = $order_range - count( $open_days );



  if ( $open_days_count !== 0 ) {
    $last_open_days = end( $open_days );
    get_store_open_days( $open_days_count, $last_open_days );
    $test[] = $open_buisness_days;

  }
  else {
    $test[] = $open_buisness_days;
    // print_r($open_buisness_days); 

  }

  $data[] = $test;

  return $data;
  
}

//current date
$initial_date = date( 'Y-m-d' );

//Get preorder range
$order_range = 5;

$get_store_days = get_store_open_days( $order_range, $initial_date );

print_r($get_store_days);
```

But it's not getting the desired result. Can someone look into this and help me where I am getting wrong?

**UPDATE**

There would be the concept of special opening date so anyhow the dates in special opening days would be open for anyhow. If the special opening days would occur in the weekdays off or in the holidays still the dates should come in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `while` condition to ensure that the loop keeps going until you've got the desired number of days in your array.

I would also advise you pass in all the parameters, don't hardcode them into your function.

```
function getStoreOpenDays($preorder = 0, $excludeDays = [], $holidays = [], $initialDate = 'now') {
    
    $days = [];
    $daysRequired = $preorder + 1;

    foreach ($holidays as $i => $date) {
        $holidays[$i] = (new DateTime($date))->format('Ymd');
    }
    $start = new DateTimeImmutable($initialDate);
    $i = 0;
    
    while (count($days) < $daysRequired) {
        $day = $start->add(new DateInterval('P' . $i++ . 'D'));
        $isExcluded = in_array($day->format('N'), $excludeDays);
        $isHoliday = in_array($day->format('Ymd'), $holidays);
        if (!$isExcluded && !$isHoliday) {
            $days[] = $day;
        }
    }
    return $days;
}
```

**Usage**

```
// Exclude Thursdays and Saturdays
$daysClosed = [4, 6];

// Set the holiday dates
$holidays = ['2020-09-15', '2020-09-18'];

// Get an array of date objects for the next 5 preorder days
$days = getStoreOpenDays(5, $daysClosed, $holidays);
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => DateTimeImmutable Object
        (
            [date] => 2020-09-14 09:27:20.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => US/Pacific
        )

    [1] => DateTimeImmutable Object
        (
            [date] => 2020-09-16 09:27:20.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => US/Pacific
        )

    [2] => DateTimeImmutable Object
        (
            [date] => 2020-09-20 09:27:20.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => US/Pacific
        )

    [3] => DateTimeImmutable Object
        (
            [date] => 2020-09-21 09:27:20.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => US/Pacific
        )

    [4] => DateTimeImmutable Object
        (
            [date] => 2020-09-22 09:27:20.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => US/Pacific
        )

    [5] => DateTimeImmutable Object
        (
            [date] => 2020-09-23 09:27:20.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => US/Pacific
        )

)
```

---

**Additional Notes**

You can work with the date objects as you wish after that:

```
foreach ($days as $day) {
    echo $day->format('Y-m-d (l)') . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
2020-09-14 (Monday)
2020-09-16 (Wednesday)
2020-09-20 (Sunday)
2020-09-21 (Monday)
2020-09-22 (Tuesday)
2020-09-23 (Wednesday)
```

If you want to start at a date other than today, use the fourth parameter:

```
$days = getStoreOpenDays(5, $daysClosed, $holidays, '2020-10-01');
```

Comment: @NadHorsie thanks for the answer. Although I have accepted the answer there is another modification I need for special opening days. So you can refer my updated question. Can you help me here also?

Basically the special opening days would be the days anyhow it would open the store. If it comes in weekdays off or in holidays still the store would be open for those days. 
Can you help me here?